# ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make a trigger which query the DB to check if a specific product has been order before allowing a delivery. I can't  change the table. I get the error: **ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here.** I do not understand what it could mean. I have to check if the bar code inside the delivery, exist in the table product and the product numreference exist in command.

The table are as follow:

Command

```
--------------------------------------------------------
NUMCOMMAND   DATE    CLIENTCODE NUMREFERENCE NUMBERITEMS
----------- -------- ---------- ------------ -----------
         53 20-11-21          2           10           5
```

Product

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 BARCODE   PRODUCTNUMBER        NUMREFERENCE   IDCLERK  STOCKQUANTITY
---------- -------------------- ------------ ---------- ---------------
         1 P001                            1          2              10
```

Delivery

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIVERIYNUMBER   DATE   CLIENTCODE NUMCOMMAND BARCODE  ID CLERK DELIVEREDQUANTITY
----------------  -----  ---------- ---------- -------  -------- -----------------
```

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER productExist
BEFORE INSERT ON DELIVERY
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_count       INTEGER;
BEGIN
  select count(*) 
    into l_count
    from C command, L delivery, P product
    where C.clientCode = :new.clientCode AND :new.barcode= P.barcode AND C.numreference = P.numreference;
  if l_count > 0 then
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Delivery accepted');
  ELSE
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20202, 'Delivery declined');  

  end if;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the following:

```
from command C, delivery L, product P
```

I think the table aliases are in the wrong place.

Comment: And once that’s fixed, there’s a cross join to every row in delivery - which you shouldn’t be referencing at all in a trigger against it (you’ll get the mutating table error on execution). The only way to refer to the row you inserted is to use the :new record.